# How to get Customer EMail id when checkout is done in without login?

Tags: checkout, customer, email

when user purchases product without logging in, how to get email or customer information in such case?

```
$ShippingData =Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
                    ->getShippingAddress()
                    ->getData();
var_dump($ShippingData);
$BillingData = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
                    ->getBillingAddress()
                    ->getData();
var_dump($BillingData);
```

getting shipping and billing data dont have email id.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$order_data = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_increment_id);
echo $order_data->getShippingAddress()->getEmail();
```

For more information you can check my article on my blog at http://pradeepsanku.com/2015/07/03/get-customer-email-id-for-guest-checkouts-in-magento-magento/

Comment: Hi @pradeep-sanku, I got this message : Fatal error: Call to a member function getEmail() on a non-object. I put that code in success.phtml.

Comment: can you show your code please ?

Comment: here is my code : http://pastebin.com/ZmrUTk98. And it work after I change it into this : 
`<?php
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
    echo $order->getCustomerEmail();
?>`

Answer (score 2):

You can get customer email id from following code

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getCustomerEmail();
```

Comment: Hi @meenakshisundaram-r, still not get the email. I put that code in success.phtml.